# svg fill path animation issue

Tags: html, animation, svg, web, svg-animate

I'm working on svg animation and trying to make the letters filled just once. When they are filled, animation must stop.

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 2000 688" enable-background="new 0 0 2000 688" xml:space="preserve">
 <linearGradient id="fill" x1="0.5" y1="1" x2="0.5" y2="0">
          <stop offset="0%" stop-opacity="1" stop-color="royalblue"/>
          <stop offset="40%" stop-opacity="1" stop-color="royalblue">
            <animate attributeName="offset" values="0;1;0" repeatCount="indefinite" dur="4s" begin="0s"/>
          </stop>
          <stop offset="40%" stop-opacity="0" stop-color="royalblue">
            <animate attributeName="offset" values="0;1;0" repeatCount="indefinite" dur="4s"  begin="0s"/>
          </stop>
          <stop offset="100%" stop-opacity="0" stop-color="royalblue"/>
      </linearGradient>
 <g id="preventive">
  <g> 
   <path fill="url(#fill)" d="M541,222c10,8.5,15,21.5,15,39c0,17.6-5.1,30.4-15.4,38.5c-10.2,8.1-25.9,12.2-46.9,12.2h-18.9v39.7h-31.7
    V209.3h50.2C515.2,209.3,531.1,213.5,541,222z M517.7,277.9c3.8-4.3,5.7-10.5,5.7-18.7c0-8.2-2.5-14-7.4-17.5
    c-5-3.5-12.6-5.2-23.1-5.2h-18.1v47.8h21.4C506.8,284.3,514,282.2,517.7,277.9z"/>
   <path fill="url(#fill)" d="M698,256.5c0,22.8-9,37.5-27.1,44.1l36,50.8h-39.1l-31.5-45.4h-22v45.4h-31.7V209.3h53.9
    c22.1,0,37.9,3.7,47.3,11.2C693.3,227.9,698,239.9,698,256.5z M659.7,273.4c3.9-3.5,5.9-9.1,5.9-16.8c0-7.7-2-12.9-6.1-15.8
    c-4.1-2.8-11.2-4.3-21.4-4.3h-23.8v42.1h23.2C648.4,278.6,655.8,276.9,659.7,273.4z"/>
   <path fill="url(#fill)" d="M834.3,209.3v28.3h-70.8v29.3h63.7v27.1h-63.7v29.5h73v28.1H731.8V209.3H834.3z"/>
   <path fill="url(#fill)" d="M923,299.8l36.2-90.5h34.4l-57.2,142.2h-26.8l-57.2-142.2h34.4L923,299.8z"/>
   <path fill="url(#fill)" d="M1116.2,209.3v28.3h-70.8v29.3h63.7v27.1h-63.7v29.5h73v28.1h-104.7V209.3H1116.2z"/>
   <path fill="url(#fill)" d="M1249.9,209.3h31.7v142.2h-31.7l-67.7-89.1v89.1h-31.7V209.3h29.7l69.8,91.5V209.3z"/>
   <path fill="url(#fill)" d="M1376.5,236.7v114.7h-31.7V236.7h-40.3v-27.5h112.3v27.5H1376.5z"/>
   <path fill="url(#fill)" d="M1439.7,209.3h31.7v142.2h-31.7V209.3z"/>
   <path fill="url(#fill)" d="M1562.1,299.8l36.2-90.5h34.4l-57.2,142.2h-26.8l-57.2-142.2h34.4L1562.1,299.8z"/>
   <path fill="url(#fill)" d="M1755.3,209.3v28.3h-70.8v29.3h63.7v27.1h-63.7v29.5h73v28.1h-104.7V209.3H1755.3z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
</svg>
```

I've used [this exampl](https://jsfiddle.net/ppy2ggpL/), but it doesn't work the way I want it to

Here is my [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/olgaivanysko/cqzgxf0L/)

Does anyone have any idea how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you don't want it to repeat then don't use repeatCount.
- If you want it to freeze as it is post animation use fill="freeze"
- I've also adjusted the values of the animation so the stop offsets just go from 0 to 1

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 2000 688" enable-background="new 0 0 2000 688" xml:space="preserve">
 <linearGradient id="fill" x1="0.5" y1="1" x2="0.5" y2="0">
          <stop offset="0%" stop-opacity="1" stop-color="royalblue"/>
          <stop offset="40%" stop-opacity="1" stop-color="royalblue">
            <animate attributeName="offset" values="0;1" dur="4s" begin="0s" fill="freeze"/>
          </stop>
          <stop offset="40%" stop-opacity="0" stop-color="royalblue">
            <animate attributeName="offset" values="0;1" dur="4s"  begin="0s fill="freeze"/>
          </stop>
          <stop offset="100%" stop-opacity="0" stop-color="royalblue"/>
      </linearGradient>
 <g id="preventive">
  <g> 
   <path fill="url(#fill)" d="M541,222c10,8.5,15,21.5,15,39c0,17.6-5.1,30.4-15.4,38.5c-10.2,8.1-25.9,12.2-46.9,12.2h-18.9v39.7h-31.7
    V209.3h50.2C515.2,209.3,531.1,213.5,541,222z M517.7,277.9c3.8-4.3,5.7-10.5,5.7-18.7c0-8.2-2.5-14-7.4-17.5
    c-5-3.5-12.6-5.2-23.1-5.2h-18.1v47.8h21.4C506.8,284.3,514,282.2,517.7,277.9z"/>
   <path fill="url(#fill)" d="M698,256.5c0,22.8-9,37.5-27.1,44.1l36,50.8h-39.1l-31.5-45.4h-22v45.4h-31.7V209.3h53.9
    c22.1,0,37.9,3.7,47.3,11.2C693.3,227.9,698,239.9,698,256.5z M659.7,273.4c3.9-3.5,5.9-9.1,5.9-16.8c0-7.7-2-12.9-6.1-15.8
    c-4.1-2.8-11.2-4.3-21.4-4.3h-23.8v42.1h23.2C648.4,278.6,655.8,276.9,659.7,273.4z"/>
   <path fill="url(#fill)" d="M834.3,209.3v28.3h-70.8v29.3h63.7v27.1h-63.7v29.5h73v28.1H731.8V209.3H834.3z"/>
   <path fill="url(#fill)" d="M923,299.8l36.2-90.5h34.4l-57.2,142.2h-26.8l-57.2-142.2h34.4L923,299.8z"/>
   <path fill="url(#fill)" d="M1116.2,209.3v28.3h-70.8v29.3h63.7v27.1h-63.7v29.5h73v28.1h-104.7V209.3H1116.2z"/>
   <path fill="url(#fill)" d="M1249.9,209.3h31.7v142.2h-31.7l-67.7-89.1v89.1h-31.7V209.3h29.7l69.8,91.5V209.3z"/>
   <path fill="url(#fill)" d="M1376.5,236.7v114.7h-31.7V236.7h-40.3v-27.5h112.3v27.5H1376.5z"/>
   <path fill="url(#fill)" d="M1439.7,209.3h31.7v142.2h-31.7V209.3z"/>
   <path fill="url(#fill)" d="M1562.1,299.8l36.2-90.5h34.4l-57.2,142.2h-26.8l-57.2-142.2h34.4L1562.1,299.8z"/>
   <path fill="url(#fill)" d="M1755.3,209.3v28.3h-70.8v29.3h63.7v27.1h-63.7v29.5h73v28.1h-104.7V209.3H1755.3z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!